# How to set multiple conditional opearator in java8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to convert the below code in java 8, but not sure where I am going wrong. I have 2 code snippets which I want to convert. This is the first one:

```
for (WebElement value :values) {
    WebElement dateElement = SharedWebDriver.getInstance()
            .findOptionalElement(By.className("text"), value);
    WebElement groupElement = 
    SharedWebDriver.getInstance().findOptionalElement(By.id("label"), 
    value);
    WebElement typeElement =  
    SharedWebDriver.getInstance().findOptionalElement(By.id("type"), 
    value);
    if (dateElement != null) {
        dateValue = dateElement.getText().trim();
    }
    if (groupElement != null) {
        groupValue = groupElement.getText().trim();
    }
    if(typeElement!= null){
        typeValue = typeElement.getText().trim();
    }
}
```

And here I want to set value using java 8. I tried it with using the filter option, but it's not working.

```
for (WebElement header : headers) {
    if (header != null) {
        if (header.getText().equals("A")) {
            entry.setDate(dateValue);
        } else if (header.getText().equals("B")) {
            entry.setGroup(groupValue);
        } else if (header.getText().equals("C")) {
            entry.setType(typeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Java 1, 2, 3... 7 code compiles fine in Java 8. You shouldn't have to change anything. If you **want** to change something, then show us what you tried doing, and tell precisely what problem you faced.

Comment: I'm agreeing with earlier comments here; this code will work fine in Java 8.  I don't see any actual wins for you if you change this to use the Stream API.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with those code snippets is that they modifiy variables defined outside of the loop (dateValue, groupValue and typeValue for the first one, and entry for the second one).
But lambda expressions are not really supposed to alter variables that are not defined in their scope event though you can achieve that throught methods.

For example, inside a lambda expression :
`word = "hello"` will not work whereas `website.setTitle("title")` will

I converted your code snippets in Java 8, I didn't take the time to test it but if I am if i am not mistaken, the first one will not work whereas the second one will, for the reason explained above.

```
values.stream()
  .map(value -> new WebElement[] {       
    SharedWebDriver.getInstance().findOptionalElement(By.className("text"), value),          
    SharedWebDriver.getInstance().findOptionalElement(By.id("label"), value)),
    SharedWebDriver.getInstance().findOptionalElement(By.id("type"), value) })
  .forEach(webElements[] -> {
    if (webElements[0] != null) {
        dateValue = webElements[0].getText().trim();
    }
    if (webElements[1] != null) {
        groupValue = webElements[1].getText().trim();
    }
    if(webElements[2] != null){
        typeValue = webElements[2].getText().trim();
    }
  });

headers.stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .forEach(header -> {
    if (header.getText().equals("A")) {
        entry.setDate(dateValue);
    } else if (header.getText().equals("B")) {
        entry.setGroup(groupValue);
    } else if (header.getText().equals("C")) {
        entry.setType(typeValue);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I would personally discourage the use of `forEach`, since that smells more like the use of an external loop more than streams.  I get that the API has this flexibility but this really takes away from its readability (since your code doesn't clean any cruft from the OP's code).

Comment: OP did want his code converted in Java 8 and there is no way to do it without forEach. Why downvoting a valid answer ? I didn't say it the good way to do it but since OP wants Java 8, well I did.

Comment: Just because that's what the OP wants doesn't mean that it's a smart approach, or even a practical approach.  Again, the fact that you're using `forEach` is still a smell in my book; streams are meant to be side effect free and the use of `forEach` is to *explicitly* allow for side effects.

Comment: I clearly say in my answer that it is not something that should be done. "But lambda expressions are not really supposed to alter variables that are not defined in their scope event though you can achieve that throught methods.". I just provided him the code so he can see the result (even though I would not have done that this way myself). So I understand your point, it just took me time to give an answer matching OP's demand and I lose reputation out of it and it's just frustrating...